# RegEx matching for URLs in HTML

Tags: html, regex, bash, shell, sed

I currently have this as my command to cut out the URL from a line that starts with `href` in HTML:

```
sed -ne 's/.*href="\([^"]*\).*/\1/p'
```

Since `href` can start with a `'` or `"` and my command only accounts for `"` right now, I was wondering how to have that command account for both `'` and `"`.

Comment: `s/.*href=("|')\([^"]*\).*/\1/p` will recognize both `"` or `'`

Answer (score 4):

```
/^(<)(.*?)(href=)("|')(.*?)(>)$/gm
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/i2QdYq/1/)

`or` is `|`.

`()` helps you to group your string step by step.

It is certainly not the best, but that online tool might help you.

Comment: And in a one liner delimited by `'` one can use `\x27` for `'`, like `/...("|\x27).../`.  There should be no need for parentheses around every element (they capture), except for the ones around the part that they are after, `.*?`, and one has to delimit the alternation, `("|\x27)`. That can also be done by non-capturing ones, `(?:"|\x27)`. The `?:` makes parens _not_ capture (remember) what's between them, but only group those things.

Comment: (the comment above is meant to be constructive/helpful, etc -- not criticism!)

Comment: Yes, that looks good, except for the parenthesis. They "capture" so that what is matched inside is then in `$1` (the first parens), `$2` (the second), etc.  So capture only what is needed later.  Judged by the question that's only the URL, so I'd put parens only around `.*?` before `>` (which matches the URL).  But, we also must have them around the alternation, `("|')`, to separate it from the rest. Since this isn't needed later, use `(?:)` (with `?:` they don't "capture" but only group). So I'd say `/^<.*?href=(?:\x22|\x27)(.*?)(?:\x22|\x27)>$/gm` and after this the URL is availble in `$1`.

Comment: [continued...]  I've added the pattern for the _closing_ quote as well. So what is captured `(.*?)` is really only the URL. Without that the `(.*?)` itself would capture the closing quote as well.

Comment: Right -- one thing is inefficiency, but also (for me) the trouble with unneeded captures is that later it's harder to keep track of which `$N` I need! If I actually need only one thing, and capture only that one, then I know it's `$1` :)